# Difference between "the usual $\mathbb{R}$" and Banach Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, euclidean-geometry, banach-spaces

I'm approaching the study of Banach spaces, and I would like to know from you, who know a lot and are actually also goot at explanations, what could be the difference between a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ definied as $f(x) = x \sin(x)$ (this is merely an example, I could have chosen something else) in the "usual context" and a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ between banach spaces ($\mathbb{R}$) defined in the same way.

I mean, is there some difference / different property in chosing Banach space in particular, instead of the "usual" $\mathbb{R}$?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ between Banach spaces? It is already between Banach spaces, but the function is not the usual class of functions for just Banach as it is not linear.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I mean: isn't there some difference between taking just $\mathbb{R}$, and taking $\mathbb{R}$ but saying it is also a Banach space? My possible confusion arises from the fact that we never say $\mathbb{R}$ is Banac. So either we understand it ALL the times in every situation, or it changes things to take it as a Banach space and not just as the "usual" field.

Comment: @Numb3rs By definition $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete ordered field. That being said we can associate an obvious Banach space to $\mathbb R$. This is the Banach space we have in mind when we talk about the Banach space $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Banach space means complete normed space. $\mathbb{R}$ is defined many times to be a completion of the absolute value norms. $\mathbb{R}$ has a lot more structure than just being a Banach space. It is also compatible with an order and is also a field. The maps people consider often when taking Banach spaces are bounded linear maps, which your $f$ is not. I might be misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the most important difference is that a general Banach space $X$ may be infinite-dimensional. This, for example, means that the unit ball
$$
B:=\{x \in X \mid ||x||\leq 1  \}
$$
is no longer compact. In the finite-dimensional case $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, the unit ball is compact independent of the norm.

Since you brought up $\mathbb{R}$, you even got more structure on $\mathbb{R}$ than on most vector spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\mathbb{R}$ is even a field!

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me in understanding why the ball is no longer compact? Does the infinite dimension of the Banach space counters the boundedness of the ball? (I think it would still be a closed surface, but maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: That is too much to explain in just a comment and is not that elementary if you have just been starting out with Banach spaces. You can find this question answered on this site multiple times on different levels and it is part of every textbook I have encountered so far. Also, I would recommend to refrain from using the term "surface" in an infinite dimensional space so far - Banach manifolds are a topic for another day!

Comment: Thank you!! Do you have some books recommendations in relation to these topic please? Our professor did not mention any book, but I’m starving to study :/